# como puedo renderizar imagenes en el footer y el header de mi pdf en NESTJS / html-pdf?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, node-html-pdf

estoy tratando de generar un pdf a través de este servicio de en NestJS, el archivo se genera correctamente, el problema es cuando intento usar una imagen como logo y una imagen en el footer, estoy usando la libreria html-pdf y he seguido su documentacion para ello, yo coloco un texto en la parte del header y el footer y automaticamente lo coloca en todas las hojas del pdf, el problema es que cuando intento colocar imagenes, solo aparece el espacio en blanco, este es mi codigo, Gracias!

```
 const pdfOptions: pdf.CreateOptions = {
  format: 'Letter',
  border: {
    top: '0',
    right: '0',
    bottom: '0',
    left: '0',
  },
  header: {
    height: '10mm',
    contents:
      '<img src="URLDEEJEMPLO.com" alt="Logo">',
  },
  footer: {
    height: "28mm",
    contents: {
      default:'<img src="URLDEEJEMPLO.com" alt="footer">',
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Asegurate de que la imágen exista realmente

Comment: Hola andres, Gracias, si he probado con distintas imagenes locales y por URL, montadas en s3 y aún asi muestra el espacio que ocupa la imagen pero no la muestra

Comment: `URLDEEJEMPLO.com` no parece la dirección de una imagen válida. ¿Has probado poner una dirección como esta: `https://i.imgur.com/WUtsRM9.png`?

Comment: Si, claro, es solo que la direccion que uso es de un s3 de la empresa, ahi coloqué que era url de ejemplo para representar cualquier imagen